# Unable to create a new nextjs project using npm create-next-app. Keeps giving error about version not being a string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I am getting this weird error when I am trying to run a newly created nextjs project using npx create-next-app@latest. I tried creating a new next app without @latest but then it gives me error like following "error ../../package.json: "version" is not a string". My node version is 18.14.0 and my npm verison is 9.3.1. Please could anyone give me a solution regarding this.

This is the error I get when I use npm create-next-app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilceQ.png

If I use npx create-next-app@latest, it is able to create a new nextjs project but when I try to run this project using npm run dev I get the following error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFENJ.png

Comment: Can you share your package.json file

Comment: {
  "name": "demo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }
}

Comment: There are no dependencies in this file

Comment: This is the file which gets created when I use npx create-next-app "my-app-name" as it gives me error while installing only.

Comment: If I use npx create-next-app@latest it creates a next project and the packege.json generated then is 
{
  "name": "api-structure",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.6",
    "next": "13.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}


but running this project via npm run dev gives me error "Invalid regular expression flags"